# OpenJPA query fails second time (possibly because of byte array parameter)

Tags: java, db2, websphere, openjpa

I have following OpenJPA query (over db2 database):

```
Select number from Number number where number.uuid = :uuid
```

Column uuid defined as VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA(16). In entity it represented as byte[] type field.

The problem is that when I call method with that query first time(after WebSphere server is up) it works fine. Consequential calls result in error (I even enabled trace log see where the error is)

```
1st time:> query is running, everything's ok
[11/25/15 13:27:03:803 IST] 0000001d Query         3   openjpa.Query: Trace: Executing query: [Select n from Number n where n.uuid = :uuid] with parameters: ?
[11/25/15 13:27:04:199 IST] 0000001d jdbc_SQL      3   openjpa.jdbc.SQL: Trace: <t 507109353, conn 1755254015> executing prepstmnt -1123134307 SELECT t0.NUMBER_ID, t0.comment, t0.EMPLOYEE_ID, t0.number, t0.RANGE_ID, t0.status, t0.uuid FROM PHONES.Number t0 WHERE (t0.uuid = ?)  [params=?]
[11/25/15 13:27:04:249 IST] 0000001d jdbc_SQL      3   openjpa.jdbc.SQL: Trace: <t 507109353, conn 1755254015> [50 ms] spent
[11/25/15 13:27:04:251 IST] 0000001d jdbc_JDBC     3   openjpa.jdbc.JDBC: Trace: <t 507109353, conn 1755254015> [0 ms] close
2nd time:>
[11/25/15 13:27:09:068 IST] 0000001d Query         3   openjpa.Query: Trace: Executing query: [Select n from Number n where n.uuid = :uuid] with parameters: ?
[11/25/15 13:27:09:556 IST] 0000001d BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "approve" on bean "BeanId(PhoneAllocationEAR#PhoneAllocationEJB.jar#RangeProvider, null)". Exception data: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1548248 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Failed to execute query "Select n from Number n where n.uuid = :uuid". Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.
```

This is nested exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.setBytes(DB2Dictionary.java:1037)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.setUnknown(DBDictionary.java:1481)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.setUnknown(DBDictionary.java:1429)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedSQLStoreQuery$PreparedSQLExecutor.executeQuery(PreparedSQLStoreQuery.java:114)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1005)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
... 86 more
```

This is code that falls with exception:

```
public String findByUUID(UUID uuid) {

    TypedQuery<Number> query = em.createQuery("Select n from Number n where n.uuid = :uuid", Number.class);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    byte[] parameter = bb.array();

    query.setParameter("uuid", parameter);

    List<Number> result = new ArrayList<Number>(query.getResultList());
    return result;
}
```

*additional info:
If I drop BIT DATA from column description - I get another error :

```
nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The value of input variable, expression or parameter number "1" cannot be used because of its data type.. SQLCODE=-301, SQLSTATE=07006, DRIVER=4.14.113 {prepstmnt 2039708348 SELECT t0.NUMBER_ID, t0.comment, t0.EMPLOYEE_ID, t0.number, t0.RANGE_ID, t0.status, t0.uuid FROM PHONES.Number t0 WHERE (t0.uuid = ?) [params=?]} [code=-301, state=07006]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLRI4A4, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -3700, 0] The value of input variable, expression or parameter number "1" cannot be used because of its data type.. SQLCODE=-301, SQLSTATE=07006, DRIVER=4.14.113 FailedObject: Select n from Number n where n.uuid = :uuid [java.lang.String]
```

I learned it from looking at source of [openJPA](https://apache.googlesource.com/openjpa/+/2.0.0/openjpa-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/DB2Dictionary.java) but it doesn't help me meanwhile.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried the latest OpenJPA. Provided stacktrace contains `openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1548248`. Also it would be nice to know your db2 and hibernate versions. I assume db2 is v9.7 FP7. (Based on the stacktrace information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable the prepared query cache. It's known to be quite buggy. You can search the OpenJPA JIRA to find details if you want.

`<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="true(EnableStatistics=true)">`

Comment: `query.setHint("openjpa.hint.InvalidatePreparedQuery", "true");` does the same thing for one query only.