# Open JPA Query fails to execute from second time in DB2 ( because of byte[] parameter)

Tags: jpa, db2, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am trying to execute the below query using Open JPA on DB2 database, it is executing fine for the 1st time after the server start up but it is failing from second time.

Query:

```
Select * from table t where t.column = ?1
```

The column is defined as CHAR(n) FOR BIT DATA in database and I am passing the parameter as String.

Though i pass the parameter as String, it is getting executed fine for the 1st time and afterwards giving below error.

```
<openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
[jcc][1083][10403][3.69.49] Illegal conversion: can not convert from
"java.lang.String" to "byte[]" ERRORCODE=-4474, SQLSTATE=null**
```

I can see a similar post, below is the link, however the solution provided not working

[OpenJPA query fails second time (possibly because of byte array parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915801/openjpa-query-fails-second-time-possibly-because-of-byte-array-parameter)

Comment: Which operating-system runs your Db2-server?  Z/OS, iSeries, Linux/Unix/Windows?  Which encoding is used for that column in the database?   Does it make a difference if you use the JDBC 4.0 driver (db2jcc4.jar), if openjpa allows that,  instead of the JDBC 3.0 driver that you are using?

Comment: Don't pass the parameter as `String`.

Comment: @mao The DB2 server is running on Linux and currently i am using JDBC 4.0 driver only with Openjpa

Comment: @mustaccio, in case i am passing byte array like string.getBytes(), i am getting Syntax exception like this, Failed to execute query . Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.